# Non-answers by non-users

Tags: bug, support, migration

Consider [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/1528/98) by a user who has not yet created an account on cs.SE (the question that has been migrated to us). It is not useful so I wanted to convert it to a comment. This causes:

```
Comment must have a valid owner
```

I see where this comes from, but is there a way around this?

Comment: This issue on the main meta: [Lift the restriction on "convert to comment" must have a valid owner on migrated questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122191)

Answer (score 5):

It's not an answer, just delete it. If you think the suggestion is good enough, you can post a comment yourself saying something along the lines of "an anonymous user suggested you try *_*."

Comment: Done so. I'm not sure how helpful the hint is (it's good, but it's pretty visible from the question), but it's there, and attributed.